# TypeScript claims Function is not Calalble

Tags: typescript

For whatever reason, TypeScript isn't detecting that something of instance Function is not callable.

```
type Constructable = { new(...args: any[]): any }

function isClass(func: any) {
  return (
    typeof func === 'function' &&
    /^class\s/.test(Function.prototype.toString.call(func))
  )
}

function coerceOne(data: any, fn: Function | Constructable) {
  if (isClass(fn)) {
    const constructor = fn as Constructable
    return new constructor(data)
  } else {
    return fn(data) // <-- ERROR
  }
}
```

Error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  No constituent of type 'Function | Constructable' is callable.(2349)
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=11&pln=14&pc=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGwCGAjAG2gF4oBvKBCAdwAoA6RnVAcyQC4ocEQBtAXQCUnbiCgBfAFCSAZugTYAloiiKkMAjiRJachSJ6DykqFFQRg6VAii0TpqKEhwZUPZijEvUAOTvgygg+UABkIfamAPQAepia2gA6SJH0wBAotABi8kqI9GCocMBF4BCpcADKaIoILPSYOAQEujmCgvbtUrI5ASqYcBComBAA8lS0ACY4uAYgADRuCJzZCr02AD6wiCgY2PhERmT2iq60ahpaOjIIbcYOUP3IwA-baFjFqJ6LXEhbT7u4QgQCJmCxWGxUagvf7vOCoSbTHDtUziKAQAhIaBHe7mSzWRYI3DIiSSKRAA

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: You are checking if `func === 'function'`, isn't suppose to be not equals?

Comment: Classes in JavaScript are functions, so yes this check is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type guard `isClass` needs a predicate return type: `: func is Constructable`

```
type Constructable = { new(...args: any[]): any }

function isClass(func: any): func is Constructable {
  return (
    typeof func === 'function' &&
    /^class\s/.test(Function.prototype.toString.call(func))
  )
}

function coerceOne(data: any, fn: Function | Constructable) {
  if (isClass(fn)) {
    const constructor = fn as Constructable
    return new constructor(data)
  } else {
    return fn(data)
  }
}

console.log(coerceOne('works', console.log))
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGwCGAjAG2gF4oBvKBCAdwAoA6RnVAcyQC4ocEQBtAXQCUnbiCgBfAFCSAZugTYAloiiKkMAjiRJachSJ7CoezKqSxEKDNnxFykqFFQRg6VAii0HjqKEhwZY3lTYlCoAHITYGUEcKgAMnjvRwB6AD1MTW0AHSQU+mAIFFoAMWDoxHowVDhgWvAIArgAZTRFBBZ6TBwCAl1gwUFvIalZcpioTDgIVEwIAHkqWgATHFwDEAAaYwROMoUKjwAfC2Q0LFxCCEF7R0VA2jUNLR0ZBEHbnymzyctz7DgqCgpDeXHM8DO1kuRGSThcbg8VGov0hF0BKzWOCGjnEUAgBCQ0DIsOcrncOwxuGxEkko2+SDgRHoBDgLFoUxmc0WEFo4WogIA1khwtt6YzGiyWINJEA